# reading and editing xml in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

how can i show just title and relase date not all xml ?

and also convert date to  to be 26.05.1995 and not 19950526

and can i use just one part of url ex. from http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113481 i just want to use  tt0113481

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim url As String = "http://mymovieapi.com/?id=" + TextBox1.Text + "&type=xml&plot=none&episode=0&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
        Dim Document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(url)
        TextBox2.Text = Document.ToString()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Element` method to read content of specified markup and use `Date.ParseExact` to parse the string date.

```
   Dim title = Document.Root.Element("title").Value()
   Dim releaseDate = Date.ParseExact(Document.Root.Element("release_date").Value, 
              "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture)
```